# iPhone making no noise except ringtones

Tags: iphone, ios, sound-volume

My wife's iPhone is playing up.  It won't make any noise except for when it revceives a call.  Messages, etc. only vibrate.  Just now it made the unlock sound when I unlocked it, but I can't get it to make the sound again.   When you press the volume keys, the **ringer** icon appears with no volume bar:

[image: ringer with no volume bar]

The lock button was also playing up for about 12 hours.  It would randomly press itself, causing the power off slide to appear or the phone to lock randomly.  That problem went away by itself.

Also:

- iPhone 4 with iOS 5.0.1
- Tried power off and hard reset
- Silent switch is off
- Silent switch mutes all sounds when on
- Bluetooth is off
- I've cleaned the dock and headphone ports
- The water damage indicator is red in the dock port and white in the headphone port (caused by baby drool)

Is there anything else software based I can try to fix this phone, or do I have to pay for repairs?

Comment: Souns like some major issues, but a quick suggestion and not really an answer, if you have the Apple headphones, what's happens when you use the built in volume controls?

Comment: @StuWilson, I see the same image as above, **ringer** with no volume bar.

Comment: then I believe this is a software issue as per Matt Love's answer, if it was hardware I'd expect the headphones would have worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the hardware in the docking port was damaged.  The phone thought there was an accessory permanently plugged in.

Also, my wife subsequently managed to smash the screen.

We paid the replacement fee for a new phone.

Answer (score 1):

It's clear that it's not a hardware issues since the sound works in certain scenarios. It seems to be a software based issue. I would suggest backing up and restoring the device using [these steps](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht4137). *Make sure* you set it up as a new device so as not to transfer any old software back to the phone after the restore.

Comment: I can't get that link to work, but I can imagine what it says.  I'll give it a go.

Comment: Sorry, it's http://support.apple.com/kb/ht4137 In my time at the Apple Store I've seen this fix for your issue dozens of times. Good luck!

Comment: Oh, and it looks like Apple's support page is temporarily down, which is why it's not working.

Comment: Got the page now.  I'll try this out next chance I get.  Thanks!

Comment: Didn't fix it.  In the end, we paid the replacement fee for a new iPhone.

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is, to clean up the headphone plugging in dock and you shall be good to go ..
(reason being - your phone is considering a headphone always being plugged in)
how to verify this fact ...?
switch the mode from silent to ringer.
It shall never show the as ringer, but shall show as headphone-silent or
headphone-ringer.
once the headphone plugging in dock is cleaned all the sounds shall work fine.